# How to add an SVG/d3 map to React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, d3.js, svg, react-native-svg

### Use Case

I want to create a React Native app that displays coordinates stored in a PostGIS database on a world map with a special map projection.

### What I have done so far

I successfully loaded the map to a React environment for my web version of the app. This is the code I implemented (only including the component that holds the map):

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

import Aux from '../../../../hoc/Auxiliary';
import styles from './Backmap.module.css';
import * as d3 from "d3";
import { feature } from "topojson-client";
import landmass from "./../../../../land-50m";

const Backmap = (props) => {

    const mapContainer = useRef(null);    

    let width = props.windowSize.windowWidth;
    let height = props.windowSize.windowHeight;

    useEffect(() => {
        const svg = d3.select(mapContainer.current)
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)

        const g = svg.append("g")

        let features = feature(landmass, landmass.objects.land).features

        let projection = d3.geoAzimuthalEqualArea()
            .center([180, -180])
            .rotate([0, -90])
            .fitSize([width, height], { type: "FeatureCollection", features: features })
            .clipAngle(150)

        let path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection)

        g.selectAll("#landmass")
            .data(features)
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("id", "landmass")
            .attr("d", path);
    }, [])


    return (
        <Aux>
            <svg
                className={styles.Backmap}
                width={props.windowSize.windowWidth}
                height={props.windowSize.windowHeight}
                ref={mapContainer}
            >
            </svg>
        </Aux>
    )
}

export default Backmap;
```

This is the resulting map from above code:

[image]

I also researched how to implement SVG shapes and even maps to React Native and came across several ways of doing so:

- [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg)(SVG)
- [React Native ART](https://hswolff.com/blog/react-native-art-and-d3/)(SVG)
- [react-native-simple-maps](https://github.com/ahushh/react-native-simple-maps)(map)

### Problem

However, I could not implement any map using these solutions. The former two in the above list don't mention any map implementation and the latter one seems to be a very early beta version. So I am wondering if this is even currently possible in React Native. Does anybody know an approach to inserting an SVG map in React native?

Comment: Its very good question, I actually look for similar solutions.. Thanks for asking this question.

Comment: @Berke I found a way of implementing it. You cannot use the `d3.select()` statement, because React Native doesn't have any `document` object. But you can use the `d3.geoPath()` function and then return the screen coordinates to a SVG `<Path>` object of the `react-native-svg` library

Comment: Yeah sounds possible. I actually thought about it to get SVG code and convert it to react-native-svg components. Could you possibly share the code example for this question and even maybe put it as answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to create d3 maps in react native. The thing is you cant use Dom selectors like d3.select().
You need to use react-native-svg. 
Read the documentation [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg) learn how to install and use it. Its implementaion is really close to the browser SVG API.

You import the Svg, G, and Path components

```
import Svg, { G, Path } from "react-native-svg";
```

You create a projection and path in the usual d3 manner.

```
let projection = d3.geoAzimuthalEqualArea()
.center([180, -180]).rotate([0, -90])
.fitSize([width, height], { type: "FeatureCollection", features: features })
.clipAngle(150)
let path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection)
```

The features are also extracted the same way.

```
let features = feature(landmass, landmass.objects.land).features
```

But we dont append components using d3. We append the Svg and G components directly.

```
return (
<Svg width='100%' height='100%'>
   <G>
   </G>
</Svg> )
```

The width and height can be styled as required.

Next the paths are appended but mapping the featurers Array to create path components.

```
return (
<Svg width='100%' height='100%'>
   <G>
      {features.map((feature, index) => {
        return (<Path d={path(feature)} key={index} stroke="black" fill="grey"></Path>)
      })}
   </G>
</Svg> )
```

If you need help in rotating the svg ask in the comments to this answer.